# Save file info in program c#

Tags: c#, .net, persistence

Is it possible to save some fields in the program, or do I have to write them to a file?

Example:

1. I open a file (with OpenFileDialog) and put it in a FileInfo
2. close the program
3. restart the program
4. go to open -> recent -> select the previous File

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use for example the settings file to store the paths to those files[(see here)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Then on startup, lookup the path in settings and create a fileinfo

Answer (score 2):

See also
[How to decide where to store per-user state? Registry? AppData? Isolated Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882490/how-to-decide-where-to-store-per-user-state-registry-appdata-isolated-storage)?

Answer (score 0):

you have to put it into a file somwhere... 
usually you use the configfile for such things. .net manages the work around this configfile very good.

Comment: any examples? (or link to examples)

Comment: see http://www.codeguru.com/columns/DotNet/article.php/c7987/
if you use VS you could also use the project settings to generate the configuration that is much easyier to use for the first time.