# When is the Program Folder created in AppData\Roaming?

Tags: windows, operating-system

When I run an executable file, a folder is created in `AppData\Roaming\` with the folder's name being the same as the executable.

I have no ideas about *when* the folder is created? Is it decided by the windows system? Is it possible to choose another place to create the folder?

I have noticed that almost every program installed on my computer has a corresponding folder under `AppData\Roaming\`. It seems that windows system will create a folder for every program installed on the computer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert, but from what I've always understood, this is the general concept.

`Appdata\Roaming` is a folder that deals with this concept of "roaming" profiles. So, for example, in a corporate environment you may log onto your Windows user profile and it pulls permissions, privileges, and/or preferences from a server your business has set up. Now, if you run any applications that the business utilizes, it will likely pull information from your `Appdata\Roaming` folders (or sometimes the registry) to validate your credentials and/or provide you with your allowed permissions (maybe you only have access to read-only privileges, for example).

The difference between `Appdata\Roaming` and `Appdata\local` or `Appdata\Locallow` can probably be identified by the naming conventions, but basically, the local stuff is meant to stay on that machine, whereas the roaming stuff may be across your entire network. So, you may access the roaming data to log in a user to your server, but you may access local folders if you have information that is specifically tied to that computer.

`Is it possible to choose another place to create the folder?`

I would imagine this is possible, but there are too many factors to say (what platform, what's the intention of the created file, etc.). I'm pretty sure that the `roaming` folder is uploaded for the corresponding user when the user logs out (again, in a corporate environment), so if you were to place your file outside of the roaming profile, that user wouldn't get his data backed up.

Again, I could be wrong about some of this. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882490/how-to-decide-where-to-store-per-user-state-registry-appdata-isolated-storage) and [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465094.aspx) if you want to know more. Hope this helped!